# How to finish running the code even after handling exceptions in python

Tags: python, exception

I'm do some calculations and append them to a list. However there are calculations that will cause a division by zero error. If that happens, I want to just append the word "error" in the list.

A sample code:

```
    try:
        for i in [1,2,3]:
            z.append(i/(i-1))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        z.append("error")
```

But the code I have stops once the error occurs so the list z would only have ["error"]. Is there a way to modify my code so that it continues until the end of the loop so z would contain ["error", 1, 2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    try:
        z.append(i/(i-1))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        z.append("error")
```